# Select EC2 region for Heroku dynos?

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2

I understand that **Heroku** is built in top of **Amazon EC2**, I was wondering if it's possible to select in which region your dynos should be spinned off, can I instruct **Heroku** to spin the dynos in the Tokyo Region for instance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right now Heroku only runs in the us-east region. My understanding is that they are working on expanding to other regions for redundancy after there was an EC2 outage which knocked them out for 8 hours or so.

**Edit**
They have just recently released the EU region. Read more at https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/4/24/europe-region